# How can I configure pub to copy a file from the root directory of my project to build/web?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

As part of the pub build process, I would like pub to copy a file from `$PROJECT_ROOT/third_party/foo/foo.png` to `$PROJECT_ROOT/build/web/foo.png` to make it accessible to my code at runtime. How can I configure pub to copy the file for me using `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. 
You can use for example [Grinder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/grinder) and automate your build tasks with it. It makes it easy to invoke `pub build` and copying files with a few lines of Dart code.

Comment: Can I write a transformer to copy the file for me?

Comment: No, AFAIK a transformer can't access files outside the top-level directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlink for that. It will be automatically copied during `pub build` to your `build` directory and will always be the same file as in your root directory during debug. 
You may symlink the whole folder or single file to your web folder.

`pub` does exactly the same with packages folder. In linux or macosx its quite easy using `ln -s` command. In windows,  [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) is good explanation how to do that.